# tmhOAuth error code 200

Tags: oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to get a users home_timeline:

```
<?php

  require_once('tmhoauth/tmhOAuth.php');

  $connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
    'consumer_key' => '*******',
    'consumer_secret' => '*******',
    'user_token' => '********',
    'user_secret' => '*********',
  )); 

  $connection -> request('GET', $connection -> url('1/statuses/home_timeline.json?include_entities=true'));

 echo($connection -> response['code']);
?>
```

And it returns error code 200.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure `200` is an _error_ code? what is the expected response code/what does the rest of response contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All is OK if the Twitter API returns 200 : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses